# AWS, Shared subscription behaviour capability of AWS MQTT broker

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot

I'm exploring AWS IoT MQTT broker capabilities for my future use and I'm trying to figure out if AWS MQTT broker supports "shared subscriptions" functionality.

Shared subscriptions, relatively new functionality, introduced by IBM MessageSight. Represents "queue" or "p2p" behavior when multiple subscribers with same clientID can be connected/subscribed to the same topic and only one subscriber instance (load is balancing automatically) receives particular message. Against of pub/sub topic model, when all subscribers receive copies, this is very convenient to use in software architecture as we don't need to use one more "player" message queue to distribute load between parallel application instances.

In case if IoT, messages published by devices can be consumed by several application instances, working in parallel, to distribute load between them.

Comment: The AWS doc is pretty good at explaining what it supports, have you looked?

Comment: Thanks @hardillb. I didn't find anything about it in documentation, just wanted to check here.

Comment: If it's not in the docs it is VERY unlikely to be supported, especially as shared subscriptions are not currently part of the MQTT spec. IBM MessageSight and HiveMQ both have different implementations of a version of shared subscriptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS IoT does **not** support Shared subscriptions but there is feature request. So we could expect it (soon).

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=757689

Answer (score 0):

Spent time on documentation and yes, unfortunately, AWS IoT MQTT does not support shared subscriptions at this point of time.